# pascal triangle in haskell nested lists

Tags: haskell, pascals-triangle

im trying to get the kth row in every list in the pascal list. For example pascal 4 would get the 4nd element in every row. So it would return 1,4,10,20... etc. I understand how to construct an infinite pascal list which is what outputs below, but im unsure of how to get a nth element in each nested list. any suggestions? i was thinking of using map, but im not necessarily mapping a function here which is throwing me off a bit. thank you.

```
// im trying to get pascal k to return the nth element of every row in the triangle
pascal n = map(\n -> ??) take n pascal 
pascal_infite = [1] : map (\l -> zipWith (+) (l ++ [0]) (0:l)) pascal_infinite
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the kth row:

```
>>> pascal_infinite !! 4
[1,4,6,4,1]
```

To get all rows from `[0..k]`:

```
>>> map (pascal_infinite !!) [0..4]
[[1],[1,1],[1,2,1],[1,3,3,1],[1,4,6,4,1]]
```

To get all rows from `[0..k]` *fast*:

```
>>> take (4+1) pascal_infinite
[[1],[1,1],[1,2,1],[1,3,3,1],[1,4,6,4,1]]
```

---

Whoops, misread the question a bit. To get what you're asking for, you should probably construct just use the good old `n choose k` formula or something similar if you're concerned about speed.

If this is just an exercise, disregarding speed, here's one way:

```
pascal n = map (!! n) $ drop n pascal_infinite
```

Then simply sample a couple of the 4th elements:

```
>>> take 8 $ pascal (4-1)
[1,4,10,20,35,56,84,120]
```

Answer (score 1):

This basically is an [**`iterate :: (a -> a) -> a -> [a]`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:iterate) function where you have a state, and each time you update the state and you thus produce a list of elements.

As iterate function, we basically want to perform a `zipWith (+)` with the previous list `xs`, and `(0:xs)`, but where we keep iterating until both lists are exhausted. We can implement a `zipWithLongest` for this:

```
zipWithLongest :: a -> b -> (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]
zipWithLongest x0 y0 f = go
    where go (x:xs) (y:ys) = f x y : go xs ys
          go [] t = map (f x0) t
          go t [] = map (flip f y0) t
```

So now we can produce the list by using:

```
import Control.Monad(ap)

pascalTriangle :: Num n => [[n]]
pascalTriangle = iterate (ap (zipWithLongest 0 0 (+)) (0:)) [1]
```

We can index the list by using the [**`(!!) :: [a] -> Int -> a`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-33--33-). Note however that this is usually a bit of an anti-pattern because of two reasons:

1. a lookup takes *O(k)* time with *k* the value of the index we want to obtain; and
2. it is a partial function in the sense that the index can be out of range (here a negative index, and for finite lists an index that is too large).

We know that every next line of the *Pascal triangle* contains one element more than the previous line. So the *k*-th line contains *k* elements. If we want to obtain the `k`-th element of every sublist, then we should first *ignore* all the lists that don't have a `k`-th element. So we use `drop k` to drop the first `k`-elements of the list, and then a `map (!! k)` to obtain the `k`-th element of every sublist that we do not filter.

So we can write a function:

```
kThPascalTriangle :: Num n => Int -> [n]
kThPascalTriangle k = map (!! k) (drop k pascalTriangle)
```